# Set basic auth on server side

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I configured resource and authorization servers in one application. I use spring-security oauth2, with Resource Owner Password Credentials. Can I set up basic auth on the server side? I don't want to do it on the front-end.
I don't know what a part of the code I need to show...
When I want to receive a token I need to enter this in postman:
[image: from postman]
Can I configure it on the server side?

Authorization Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).tokenEnhancer(jwtTokenEnhancer).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/login");
    }
}
```

Resource Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html#").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Bean
    protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
        converter.setSigningKey("Demo-Key-1");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

    @Override
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .and().cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is accompanied by a [complete and working sample](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/tree/92ab3672c819ef0d6407a6da16f9529c7a11c652/samples/legacy-spring-sec-oauth2)*.

Maybe you are [biting off more than you can chew](https://www.google.com/search?q=bite+off+more+than+you+can+chew&oq=Bite+Off+More+Than+You+Can+Chew) here?

For example:

```java
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
```

The `/oauth/token` endpoint must remain protected. This is the endpoint on the authorization server that issues tokens to authenticated clients. The system will probably fail with `NullpointerException` or other exceptions if you open it, however, the above configuration option indicate that maybe you're a bit confused about how OAuth2 works.

What I would recommend is to first fully understand authorization server versus resource server. You can definitely combine the two, but they would have very different endpoints.

Authorization Server - typical endpoints

```
/oauth/token - issues tokens
/oauth/authorize - issues authorization codes
/introspect - validates a token and returns token claims in a known format
```

Resource Server - These would be your application endpoints, requiring `Bearer` tokens, for example

```
/account/123/debit
```

and these endpoints expect a stateless request that has an authorization header

```
Authorization: Bearer <token value here>
```

A controller for a resource server would look like this:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('your-scope-role')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
@ResponseBody
public String hello(Principal principal) {
    return "Hello to " + principal.getName();
}
```

Feel free to review the [simple project](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/tree/92ab3672c819ef0d6407a6da16f9529c7a11c652/samples/legacy-spring-sec-oauth2) that I have created for you.

In addition to that, I also recommend this video on [OAuth2 and OpenID Connect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4BHKcZ2rxk)

In my sample, I have configured the [clients](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/819c6af625d5b7aa6b822048ee0f72b65d8630da/samples/legacy-spring-sec-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/SecurityConfig.java#L87-L105) like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        InMemoryClientDetailsService clientDetails = new InMemoryClientDetailsService();
        BaseClientDetails client = new BaseClientDetails(
            "testclient",
            null,
            "testscope,USER,ADMIN",
            "password",
            null
        );
        client.setClientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"));
        clientDetails.setClientDetailsStore(
            Collections.singletonMap(
                client.getClientId(),
                client
            )
        );
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetails);
    }
```

Take a look at this simple test case, the client is using http-basic authentication:

```java
mvc.perform(
    post("/oauth/token")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
            .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .param("username", "admin")
            .param("password", "password")
            .param("grant_type", "password")
            .param("response_type", "token")
            .param("client_id", "testclient")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String("testclient:secret".getBytes()))
```

This is client authentication, using the http-basic method:

```java
.header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String("testclient:secret".getBytes()))
```

Comment: My question is, what endpoint should have basic authentication and why? a resource server would use tokens, and the authorization server is predefined

Comment: Ok. Can I set to authorization server client_id and client-secret ? And don`t enter it in the postman?

Comment: @lorlor I'm not sure what you are asking. The client_id and client_secret MUST be passed EVERY time when you try to get a token from /oauth/token. You can't, _and you should not_, work around that.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and is exactly the depth and quality we're looking for here. Good work!